# How to trigger notification sound when onmessage event occur using django channels?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, websocket, django-channels

I have created a chat website using django channels and want to play some audio as notification alert when any message was send / received between users.
can anyone could help me in resolving it ?

Answer (score 0):

Call this function in javascrict in your "message received" event.

```
function playSound() {
    var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: I got error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first."

Comment: Yes, you have to interact with the DOM first. That's a rule in all browsers.